# ZFS dataset doesn't automatically mount

Tags: freebsd, zfs

Running on a FreeBSD 12.0 system, a dataset (my home directory) does not mount automatically at system boot. Manually mounting it (i.e. via `zfs mount zroot/usr/home/username`) works correctly.

This dataset originally was on a different disk and was moved to its current location via `zfs send deskback/backup/usr/home/username | zfs receive -e zroot/usr/home`.

Presumably, I could add an entry to `/etc/fstab` to mount this dataset, but it seems like this shouldn't be necessary. How can I get ZFS to automatically mount this at boot time?

**Edit**

The `canmount` property for these datasets are:

```
# zfs get -r canmount zroot/usr
NAME                             PROPERTY  VALUE     SOURCE
zroot/usr                        canmount  off       local
zroot/usr/home                   canmount  on        default
zroot/usr/home/username          canmount  on        default
zroot/usr/home/username@--head-- canmount  -         -
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 'zfs_enable="YES"' in /etc/rc.conf right? This is what mounts all datasets at boot, it basically runs `zfs mount -a` to mount all ZFS datasets

Answer (score 3):

Check that the `canmount` property is set to `on`, and not to `noauto` or `off`.

If you see this, you have a problem:

```
# zfs get canmount zroot/usr/home/<username>
NAME                       PROPERTY  VALUE     SOURCE
zroot/usr/home/<username>  canmount  noauto    default
```

Fix it with:

```
# zfs set canmount=on zroot/usr/home/<username>
```

You may also want to check the parent datasets.

Answer (score 0):

to mount automatically `zdata` pool run:

```
zpool set cachefile=/boot/zfs/zpool.cache zdata
```

It will save currently mounted pools to cache and when reboot import this pool automatically.

Of course, zfs parameter `canmount` for this pool has to be set to on

```
zfs set canmount=on zdata
```